# Magento2 : How to bind custom Knockout Method to a data-bind?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I need the product URL for each product in the checkouts cart.

Therefore I want to edit `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/web/templates/summary/item/details.html` and add my custom method there, lets call it `myMethod`.

This is how my code looks like right `<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name, myMethod:{}"></strong>`.

However, in a console, i have the log that there's no function called `myMethod`. Logic!

How can I create `myMethod` in Order to let it work? Where do I need to inject my JS?

What do I want to do? For legal reasons, I need the URL of the product. I want KO to do my request by calling an ajax file that returns the URL of the product and then links it. The final code in `details.html` will look like this:

`<a class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name, myMethod:{}"></a>`

In `onepage.phtml` I've added the following to test, but it does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'ko'
    ], function($, ko) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.myMethod = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                jQuery(this).css("background-color","red");
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

How can I achieve what I what?

Answer (score 10):

For Magento to apply the bindings you need to add your Knockout JS using the UI Components like so:

#### Inside the PHTML Template file

Pay extra attention to `example-scope` as it needs to match the scope of the markup.

Component links to your JS file, and template links to your HTML (or PHTML) file that contains the data-binds (and scope).

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "example-scope": {
                    "component": "VENDOR_MODULE/js/name-of-your-js-file",
                    "template": "Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<div data-bind="scope: 'example-scope'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

#### Inside your JS file

```
define(['jquery', 'ko'], function($, ko) {
    return function(config) {
        // YOUR SCRIPT HERE
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi in case i don't use script with x-magento-init , can i use bind ko to element inside js ? Ex: specific id element in js code to binding data
ko.applyBinding(data, '#id_element')

Comment: I don't think you can use applyBindings within Magento 2, this was the first thing I tried but it stopped the KO in Magento from working.

Comment: @BenCrook, I did same but i don't get output.

Comment: @Sarfaraj Have you cleared browser cache and Magento cache? You may possibly need to redeploy static content or setup symlinks again depending on your workflow.

Comment: @BenCrook, yes i have applied deploy commands and also clear browser cache.

Comment: I'm not sure then sorry, if you ask a new question and include your code and the steps taken me or someone else should be able to help.

Comment: @BenCrook, I post a question please see this.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198827/magento2-while-bind-custom-knockout-js-to-html-it-return-only-default-value

Comment: Hi @BenCrook . Can you please see this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/257814/17154

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve that first, you should modify:

`details.html:`

`<div data-bind="text: someAction($parent)"></div>`

This an entry point for debbuging. You have to find corresponding js file. In `Magento\Checkout\...\web\js\...\details.js` you should add this `someAction()` method. Here you can put `console.log()` and searching around. I was modyfying OneStepCheckout by Magestore, but I bet you can use that (add it inside below other functions), one or make some modifications:

`details.js`:

```
 /**
         * Method gets product object basing on quoteItem and quote object.
         *
         * @param {object} quoteItem
         *
         * @return {object}
         */

        getProductOfQuoteItem: function(quoteItem) {
            var quoteItemId = quoteItem.item_id;
            var quoteItemCollection = quote.getItems();
            for (var i in quoteItemCollection) {
                if (quoteItemCollection[i].item_id == quoteItemId) {
                   return quoteItemCollection[i];
                }
            }
       },
```

Here you should have product object, but it has only part of data. If you don't have information you need you can add them using observer: on `sales_quote_item_set_product`

and in observer you can add data more or less like this (I was adding some category data):

```
class addDataToQuoteItem implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $categoryRepository;


    /**
     * Di.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    public function __construct
    (
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepositoryInterface
    )
    {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepositoryInterface;
    }


    /**
     * Method adds custom data to every quote item object.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        /** @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface */
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

        $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        /** @var $quoteItem \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface */

        //To inject it as attribute, not using setData() you need xml, provided below
        $quoteItem->setCategoryIds($product->getCategoryIds());

        //That way you don't need any xml
        $quoteItem->setData('categoryData', $categoryIds);
    }
}
```

and xml if using first method in observer - `etc\catalog_attributes.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
<group name="quote_item">
    <attribute name="category_ids"/>
</group>
```

I was doing all this on module modifing default `Magento_Checkout` (aparat observer - it works on native event), so I can't promise that it will work at once, but you have some starting point to work it out.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your good answer @Ben Crook.

Add another way to add the template:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "example-scope": {
                    "component": "VENDOR_MODULE/js/name-of-your-js-file",
                    "customMessage": "<?php echo __("Testing message.");?>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<div data-bind="scope: 'example-scope'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

In your js file, we can declare the template:

*VENDOR_MODULE/js/name-of-your-js-file*

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent'
], function ($, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'VENDOR_MODULE/yourtemp',
            customMessage: 'Default Text Ready'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super(); // Remember to add this
            console.log(this.customMessage); // Will print "Testing message."
            ......
        }
    });
});
```

Your template should be under `VENDOR_MODULE/view/frontend/web/template/yourtemp.html`

Comment: I did same but i don't get output.

Comment: I updated my answer. Try to clear cache. One more thing, is that your question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/198827/33057

Comment: yes that is my question.