# How to pass a Magento 2 variable to KnockoutJS

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I want to pass `$vendor_city` to knockoutJS:

```
<?php
    $vendor_city = $vendor->getData('city');
?>

<div id="m2-component" data-bind="scope:'ko'">
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#m2-component": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "ko": {
                        "component": "some_mdl/js/estimate",
                        "template" : "some_mdl/estimate"
                    } // How do I pass a variable here to estimate.js?
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

**estimate.js**

```
define(['uiComponent', 'ko', 'jquery'], function (Component, ko, jquery) {

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function (config) {
            var self = this;
            this._super();

            // I want get that variable here

        },
});
```

---

I already done like this:

```
<script>
    window.sellerlocation= '<?=$vendor_city;?>';
</script>
```

But I want to pass a PHP variable to KnockoutJS via a KnockoutJS component initialize, not a JavaScript window object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
<?php
    $vendor_city = $vendor->getData('city');
?>

<div id="m2-component" data-bind="scope:'ko'">
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#m2-component": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "ko": {
                        "component": "some_mdl/js/estimate",
                        "template" : "some_mdl/estimate",
                        "vendorCity": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $vendor_city ?>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

**estimate.js**

```
define(['uiComponent', 'ko', 'jquery'], function (Component, ko, jquery) {

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function (config) {
            var self = this;
            this._super();
            console.log(config.vendorCity);
        },
});
```

Make sure that **$vendor_city** data is in encode format.

**[Refresh your JavaScript code](https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/), clean the cache, and check the output in the console.**

Comment: It give me error, `Cannot read property '*' of undefined` section-config.js:33

Comment: where you use *?

Comment: nowhere, It give this error on `"vendorCity": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $vendor_city ?>` when I remove this line, error gone.

Comment: you need to use quotes like  "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $vendor_city ?>"

Comment: thanks @RohanHapani +1 for you answer. please update it according my last comment.

Comment: It's not necessary to add into double quote. Still, we can use as Ramkishan said or change it like : "vendorCity": <= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $vendor_city; ?>

Comment: @Ramkishan Thanks, it fixed. Rohan Thanks

Comment: It is working very well, but what if you need to pass a variable not to be cached in phtml?